# How can I use a linear-gradient in a VS Code theme?

Tags: css, json, visual-studio-code, themes

I am creating a theme for VS Code and would like to use a linear gradient on a few components. The problem I'm running into is that when I use linear-gradient in [the theme.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme), VS Code is only displaying the first color in the gradient.

I have searched for days online for an answer to this dilemma and can't seem to find even a morsel of help on the topic.

Comment: I had created an issue to get gradients in decorators and had no upvote. They are allowed by the core VSC team to use in the UI because the new edit markers are linear gradients

Comment: Does https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css solve your problem / answer your question?

Comment: Not really. If I remember correctly I tried that several months ago and didn't like the error/warning that it threw when using it. I would like to find a way to do it directly in the json file if at all possible.

Comment: what is the name of the theme you found with the gradients

Comment: I honestly don't remember. I came across it months before I decided to make a theme with gradients. I do remember that the theme I found was pretty awful looking but I thought it was cool that they were able to use a gradient on text and borders. When I started this theme project that was my first thought--go and find that theme to see how they did it.

Comment: Is your issue with VS Code still open? I will definitely upvote it if I haven't already.

Comment: perhaps the theme you're talking about is [`RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode)? (from its readme though: "_To enable the glow, the extension has to modify the internal files of VS Code, so use with caution._")

Comment: That might be it, though I'm not entirely sure. Reading the description of it makes me think that it is it. I see that there is a gradient on the tab in the screenshot so I'll have to install that theme and take a look at it's theme files. Thank you for that.

Comment: "_The problem I'm running into is that when I use linear-gradient in the theme.json file, VS Code is only displaying the first color in the gradient._" would you mind showing the code for that (a [mre])?

Comment: I will toy around with it again this week and see what I did to get it to show only the first color in the gradient that I declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradients are not currently supported in VS Code colour customizations / colour themes.

There are extensions that allow you to write custom CSS, or theme extensions that contribute custom CSS to achieve gradients through non-standard means. Ex. <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with these extensions)</sub></sup>

- [`be5invis.vscode-custom-css`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)
- [`RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode)

Both work by modifying what are supposed to be more-or-less internal VS Code files, which will cause VS Code to issue a corruption warning (which you can mark to not be shown again through the gear button menu), and those file modifications may need to be re-done upon VS Code updates, so it's not really ideal, but at the moment, it appears to be the only way to get theme gradients.

For example, to see how the synthwave extension does the VS Code modification, see its [`src/extension.js`](https://github.com/robb0wen/synthwave-vscode/blob/master/src/extension.js) file. For the custom CSS extension, see its [`src/extension.js`](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css/blob/master/src/extension.js) file- particularly the `performPatch` function. They both read internal VS Code files, modify them, and write the result back to the filesystem.

There's a feature request for such theming and customization functionality: [[themes] Allow gradients along with colors #92736](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92736). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues color gradient`".

Answer (score -1):

```
    .className {
  background: #FF4E50;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
}
```

try this, if not work then can you please share your code?

Comment: I know how to make a linear-gradient in css. The problem is that all theme styling is done using a theme.json file with only certain targetable attributes such as `"editor.background": "#FF4E50",` and there isn't a css file to apply styles to.

Answer (score -1):

I've looked into and am currently reigniting the spark of curiosity to figure this out, as well.
The closest thing I've been able to find is by downloading a vsCode extension called 'Indent Rainbow' which allows you to add colors to each indent column directly within your editor to give an effect like the image below if you run this snippet:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlLLl.png" />
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out a way through my research either to create a gradient with JSON keys and values without being able to iterate over it with javascript - but that only applies to an application that I'm building - not the vsCode code editor itself.
If you come across anything more verbose than creating a gradient of sorts by coloring individual indent columns; but to the actual color theme you're designating in your settings.json workspace, I'd love to hear about it! :)